# Javascript only Not selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question.

How can I can I apply a effect to this span ("infoTexts") with Javascript without touching the "phoneClose"?? (Give a example, not answer please) I know it's with the nth-child but i'm not being able to do anything at all)

Thank you and sorry for my kinda bad english :P

```
<span id="infoTexts">
        <span style="padding-right:10px;padding-left:370px;">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Info@tpc.com</span>
        <i id="phoneClose" class="fa fa-phone" style="position:relative" onclick="hideForm();"></i> &nbsp;(+351) <b>913937014</b> </span>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do to "infoTexts"?

Comment: And why are you giving ids and classes to an <i> tag? Why are you using <i> tag at all? It is better to do any styling with CSS.

Comment: I'm using i's for a special font -.- 
I'm hiding the infoTexts. And why i deserved a -1? ...

Comment: I didn't down vote you, so I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this works for you instead http://jsfiddle.net/XPE3w/2527/

```
document.getElementById('infoTexts').className = "fa fa-close";
var children = document.getElementById('infoTexts').children;
for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {   
   if (children[i].id != 'phoneClose')
   {
      children[i].className = "fa fa-close";
   }
}
```

Comment: It's exactly this that I wanted, thank you very much! (Still can't understand why people just downvote something just because my english doesnt help when i'm trying to explain...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to set style on span ("infoTexts").

```
document.getElementById('infoTexts').style.property=new style
```

However, to prevent "phoneClose" to inherit style you set on span ("infoTexts"), you need to manually  revert style changes.

Comment: That will take me to the same thing.

Comment: @DinisFigueira I don't quite get what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: I want to make in javascript something like this.... document.getElementById('infoTexts').className = "fa fa-close"; The thing is that i want to change the whole span(whose ID is 'infoTexts') except one item inside of it (a <i> tag)